# jsPhylogSVG Pathing Directory

Tags: javascript, html, path, raphael

I'm very new to the scripting business (especially in HTML and JavaScript).

Recently I was using the jsPhyloSVG code in order to make a phylogenic tree in HTML through JavaScript.

Website: http://www.jsphylosvg.com

However, I'm having problems in implementing their code. I can't seem to load anything on whenever trying out their source examples.

One of their code examples looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    # Javascript code goes here
</head>
<body>
    <div id="svgCanvas"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/raphael/raphael-min.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsphylosvg-min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
        var dataObject = { newick: '(((Espresso:2,(Milk Foam:2,Espresso Macchiato:5,((Steamed Milk:2,Cappuccino:2,(Whipped Cream:1,Chocolate Syrup:1,Cafe Mocha:3):5):5,Flat White:2):5):5):1,Coffee arabica:0.1,(Columbian:1.5,((Medium Roast:1,Viennese Roast:3,American Roast:5,Instant Coffee:9):2,Heavy Roast:0.1,French Roast:0.2,European Roast:1):5,Brazilian:0.1):1):1,Americano:10,Water:1);' };
        phylocanvas = new Smits.PhyloCanvas(
            dataObject,
            'svgCanvas', 
            500, 500
        );
};
</script>
```

When I attempt to run it in Notepad++ as a HTML file, I get a blank loading page.

Online example: http://www.jsphylosvg.com/examples/1-load-simple-tree.php

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in implementing the jsPhyloSVG code in my notepad.

The JavaScript files I downloaded alongside:*jsphylosvg.js*,*jsphylosvg-min.js*,*raphael-min.js*

Which are included in the sites' download v1.55 version.

The site tells me to simply make a HTML skeleton with

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/raphael/raphael-min.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsphylosvg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="svgCanvas"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I believe it is with directory pathing in the  src reference, but I don't know how to reference the right directory. I've tried copy pasting the directory as well (to the javascript files), but it didn't seem to work.